# Not possible to statically link libgnutls.a

Tags: c++, compilation, g++, static-libraries, gnutls

I try to link the gnutls library statical (libgnutls.a). I already did something like this with OpenSSL, which worked out perfectly wit the command line: **g++ test.cpp -statical -lcrypto -ldl -o test**. But if I try right the same with the gnuTLS library(**g++ test.cpp -statical -lgnutls -ldl -o test**), I get a lot of errors like this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.a(privkey.o): In Funktion `_gnutls_privkey_decode_ecc_key':
(.text+0x818): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `asn1_create_element'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.a(privkey.o): In Funktion `_gnutls_privkey_decode_ecc_key':
(.text+0x86a): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `asn1_der_decoding'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.a(privkey.o): In Funktion `_gnutls_privkey_decode_ecc_key':
(.text+0x8d3): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `asn1_read_value'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls.a(privkey.o): In Funktion `_gnutls_privkey_decode_ecc_key':
```

Is there a possibility to link the gnuTLS library statical?

Comment: see here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=164934

Comment: @Azad The only way proposed at this link, is to add libtasn1. If i add this library, the error remains the same.

Comment: do you have libtasn1 static object? also you are using the latest version right?

Comment: cause they mentioned it's fixed upstream

Comment: Yes I do have it (libtasn1.a). For the version, I think so, just downloaded it today: Version 3.2.11

Comment: can you post result of `nm /path/libtasn1.a | grep asn1_create_element` put the appropriate path in there

Comment: U asn1_create_element ...........\n
00000830 T asn1_create_element.............\n    Sorry for Format

Comment: did you place -ltasn1 before -lgnutls or after it?

Comment: symbols of static objects are resolved from left to right

Comment: I just tried both without success, error remains the same.

Comment: where is your libtasn1.a?

Comment: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.a

Comment: where is libgnutls.a ?

Comment: try `-L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` before `-ltasn1`

Comment: still remains the same error

Comment: is this the only libtasn1.a on your system? (cause your libgnutls.a path in the error is different) try `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libtasn1.a` instead of `-ltasn1`

Comment: Yes it is the only libtasn1.a, and if I use the path instead, it makes no difference

Comment: sorry I have no more idea you might want to statically link only one library in that case you can try this `-Wl,-Bstatic,-lgnutls,Bdynamic` (no space)

Comment: thank you for you help, but that also doesn't solve the problem.